# Relative Symlinks on a NFS Share

Tags: git, symlink, nfs, git-annex

I've set up a NFS share on my Linux server, with this line in `/etc/exports`:

```
/vol/int0     192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

However, this share primarily contains git repositories, or more specifically, [git-annexes](https://git-annex.branchable.com/). That is, the repositories primarily contains relative symlinks to a location inside the `.git/annex` directory. Now, this works fine to access on a Linux machine but on Windows the symlinks doesn't show up at all (With the official NFS client). If I navigate into the `.git/annex` folder though, the files are still there, it's just the symlinks that are missing.

Is there any way of configuring Windows to actually see the symlinks, or is it simply not possible (yet)?

(Also, I'm aware that `git-annex` can run in a "direct" mode, without the symlinks but I would like to avoid that if at all possible.)

Comment: Does your version of Windows & filesystem support symlinks?

Comment: I have no idea if my version of Windows /actually/ support symlinks (latest version of Windows 10 Pro), that's part of the question above. The filesystem underlying the NFS share naturally supports symlinks.

Comment: Who is that part of the question if you didn't provide any details about your system? That should actually be a separate StackOverflow question, "How do I know if my filesystem supports symlinks?".

Comment: I *know* that the remote filesystem (ext4) supports symlinks and I have verified that those exist and work using a separate Linux machine. All of that should be clear from the description above. Which particular filesystem it is should be irrelevant to this question as long as it is known that it actually supports symlinks.

Comment: Oh, you're not cloning from NFS into Windows. My bad.